# Making 3D plane look 2D

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, 2d, scenekit

I'm building a 3D app that uses SceneKit. My scene will have various 3D objects and a moveable perspective camera.

The user can load a 2D image into the scene, which I will display on a 3D plane using the image as the material.

What I need to be able to do is to initially show the image as if it were actually 2D, where the pixel width and height are the same as the image and it is not distorted by the camera perspective. So basically I need to know how to position that plane in relation to the camera to make it look 2D.

Thanks in advance for any tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear where you are getting stuck.

If you're just looking for where to start, look at `SCNPlane` and `SCNBillboardConstraint`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know `SceneKit`, so what I suggest might not be doable in the specific program, but **could you perhaps use an orthographic camera perspective?** It removes a lot of the visual depth from a scene, combining that with some flat lighting might accomplish the look you are going for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) . The camera will be a perspective camera with other 3D objects in the scene that need to be shown in perspective. What I need is to be able to position a 3D plane in the scene so that it looks 2D.